# TFS-CI build failing due to 'project.assets.json' not having target for .NETCoreApp, Version2.0

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, .net-standard

My console project is running 4.7.1 (`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`)

which references a .NET Standard 2.0 project "TimeUtility":

The solution builds fine locally, however the following error appears on the CI Build:

> Project
>   "C:\TFS\agent_work\21\s\Services\Daemons\ReportDaemon\ReportDaemon\ReportDaemon.sln"
>   (1) is building
>   "C:\TFS\agent_work\21\s\Core\TimeUtility\src\TimeUtility\TimeUtility.csproj"
>   (14:15) on node 1 (default targets). PrepareForBuild:   Creating
>   directory "bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\". C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5):
>   Error : Assets file
>   'C:\TFS\agent_work\21\s\Core\TimeUtility\src\TimeUtility\obj\project.assets.json'
>   doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. Ensure that
>   restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.0' in the
>   TargetFrameworks for your project. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.1.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(167,5):
>   error : Assets file
>   'C:\TFS\agent_work\21\s\Core\TimeUtility\src\TimeUtility\obj\project.assets.json'
>   doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. Ensure that
>   restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.0' in the
>   TargetFrameworks for your project.
>   [C:\TFS\agent_work\21\s\Core\TimeUtility\src\TimeUtility\TimeUtility.csproj]
>   Done Building Project
>   "C:\TFS\agent_work\21\s\Core\TimeUtility\src\TimeUtility\TimeUtility.csproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.

I've tried multiple ideas but have been usuccessful thus far.

**.Net Framework 4.7.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{66A8B6CC-ED2E-43B5-B91E-6F018B827DD4}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>ReportDaemon</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ReportDaemon</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>
    </StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Unity.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>        
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\Core\TimeUtility\src\TimeUtility\TimeUtility.csproj">
      <Project>{183d4773-b251-4989-9fc3-e0d2647d477e}</Project>
      <Name>TimeUtility</Name>
    </ProjectReference>        
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="ServiceConfig.xml" />
    <Content Include="Templates\ReportFailed.html">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Templates\ReportReady.html">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**.Net Standard 2.0 csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>TimeUtility</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>TimeUtility</PackageId>

    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**EDIT:** Added some images for clarification

[image]

[image]

Comment: What task are you using to build the projects? Do you perform a NuGet restore during the build?

Comment: @MartinUllrich Yes, NuGet restore is part of the process. I added a couple images to clarify

Comment: `The solution builds fine locally, however the following error appears on the CI Build` Suggest you also try to remote to the build agent and build with VS or command line in the build agent directly not through TFS. This will narrow down if the issue is related to your build agent environment such as lacking nuget package or TFS server side issue. Make sure your local environment is the same as your build agent environment.

Comment: Does it work if you build the project manually on the build agent?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT Yes, Everyone has been able to build this locally. I am going to try Patrick's suggestion to help narrow down the possibilities